# How to customise direction of bookmark dropdown in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I use the bookmark bar in Google Chrome quite a bit, and have a few folders with a lot of bookmarks in them. I noticed a few months ago, when I click on a folder to open it up, the bookmark list appears to the right, instead of underneath.

Is there a way to change it, so the dropdown list always shows under the folder I click on, and not beside?

Comment: have you updated to the latest version of chrome?

Comment: @hinekyle As far as I know, Chrome always updates itself to the latest version behind the scenes.